# It is possible to get data from a mapping using loop?

Tags: solidity

Suppose there is a mapping : `mapping (address => bool) public owners;`
I passed a array of owners in constructor and set 2 addresses as owner from deploy script.
so after deploying we have 2 owners.
Now i added a function for adding owners [ public function ] and updating our mapping with entering owners addresses which we are getting from this function.
It is possible to get all values of that mapping by looping? or are there any other process to do it?? I want to get all value.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't loop directly through a mapping in Solidity.
But you can loop through arrays, so either you change your code to use an array instead of a mapping, or maybe better, add a keys array to loop through alongside your mapping, like this:

```
mapping (address => bool) public owners;
address[] public getAllOwners;
```

This way you have a public method to retrieve all owners implemented for you, and if you still need to loop through all the owners, you can do it with that array, like:

```
uint len = getAllOwners.length;
for (uint i; i < len; ++i) {
    // do whatever with owners[getAllOwners[i]]
}
```

Don't forget to keep both array and mapping in sync, when adding and deleting elements...

Hope this helps.